# TestCafe does not route properly with react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, testing, automated-tests, react-router-dom, testcafe

I'm attempting to use TestCafe for E2E testing in a react app. The react app uses react-router-dom, so it has a routing section like:

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
        <Route path='/about' component={About} />
        ...
        <Route component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Test cafe loads via proxy, so in local environments, it has a path like (approximately) `http://172.24.160.0:54004/http://localhost:8080/login`. As a result, react-router-dom cannot match the path properly, and it results in the NotFound path.

Does anyone know about any workarounds for this issue? It seems unusable in its current state.

Comment: Could you try using a relative path instead of absolute? i.e.: `${match.url}/login`

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the issue. Could you please share the link to your page or find the website that demonstrates the same behavior with the testcafe? If you can't find or share link you can prepare a sample example, which demonstrates the issue and create a separate ticket in the testcafe github repository using the following link https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md, but please make sure to follow the bug template.

Comment: @AlexKamaev The project is for a business, so I cannot share a link, but when I have time, I will create a minimal repo for testing.

Comment: @ioseph Although I can't use `match` from `with-router` on the routes themselves, I am experimenting with a hacky workaround that uses `window.location`. When I have a workable solution, I will post it here.

Comment: There is a closed issue with a similar topic in the TestCafe repository: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3337. I think you can try to contact the author and ask him about his solution.